# Start services only when really required

Tags: boot, apache2, mysql

I use my desktop box as dev "server", so I have installed mysql+apache+whatever. This causes boot to last longer, also memory consumption is high since I have all this services running.

Does a software exists which can start a given service only when its port is accessed?

Say: start apache only when there's a request on localhost:80 and so on.

Comment: The system that starts services on demand was, traditionally, `inetd`, which has a modern implementation on `xinetd`. I do not think that Ubuntu uses it by default, but this can be an hint for googling more...

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use knockd to do it if you really wanted to.  I also have quite a few daemons installed for various uses, and I tend to just disable them starting on bootup and manually start them when I need them.  The command to do so would be:

```
sudo update-rc.d $serviceName disable
```

and then the obvious

```
sudo service $serviceName start
```

when you actually want it running.

The knockd conf I can think of off the top of my head would look something like:

```
[ApacheHTTP]
    sequence = 80
    seq_timeout = 10
    command = /usr/bin/service apache2 start
    tcpflags = syn
    cmd_timeout = 10
```

etc, etc for all of the services you want.  This will not automatically stop them, however.  You can add a line that says 'stop_command = /usr/bin/service apache2 stop' if you want, but this could shut it down without you wanting to.

Comment: indeed I'm now using this solution...

Comment: I added what the knockd.conf would look like.  It's not a perfect solution, but it's the best I can think of to do this without doing a bunch of scripting yourself.

Comment: it doesn't work as-is, at least here on 14.04. I will check it out lately and report back, thanks so far!

Comment: Derp.  Apparently knockd forces you to use 3 knocks, I had no idea.  I was able to use it to start and restart AppArmor, just replace 'sequence = 80' with 'sequence = 80,80,80'.  It will force you to hit the page twice before it will start, but that will work.  You also probably want to drop the 'cmd_timeout' line, it kept timing out on mine.  Perhaps accessing it through /etc/init.d would return correctly to prevent knockd thinking it timed out.